# Couldn't convert C program to Ruby

Tags: c, ruby

This code in C language works perfectly, I will explain what it does:
Given a positive integer "n" and a sequence of "n" integers, the sum will determine a sequence of positive integers.
Examples of inputs:
4 9 -1 4 -2
expected output:  13 / input: 3 3 0 -2 output: 3/

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int cont=0,n,num,sum;
    scanf("%i",&n);
    while(n>cont){
        cont++;
        scanf("%i",&num);
        if(num>0){
        sum=num+sum;
        }
    }
    printf("%i",sum);
}
```

and this was my attempt to convert it to Ruby

```
cont=0
n=gets.to_i
while n>cont do
  cont=cont+1
  num=gets.to_i
      if num>0
    sum=num+sum
  end

  puts"#{sum}"
```

and this is what im getting:

```
 ruby test.rb                                                   
test.rb:10: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end              
  puts"#{sum}"                                                                        
              ^
```

. Can anyone help?

Thank you, so this is the right code that works

```
cont=0
sum=0 
n=gets.to_i
while n>cont do
  cont=cont+1
  num=gets.to_i
  sum=num+sum if num>0
end

puts"#{sum}"
```

Comment: Sorry for not specifying that, im getting this error est.rb:9: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end               
  print"#{sum}"                                                                       
               ^

Comment: I rewrote the question.

Comment: The `if num>0` part makes that it does not work for negative numbers. Just get rid of it, Ruby is fine with `2+-1` (being 1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were not far off. The syntax of the if-statement needs a `then` and an `end`. Also, `sum` needs to be zero at the start.

```
cont=0
sum=0  # sum needs an initial value
n=gets.to_i
while n>cont do
  cont=cont+1
  num=gets.to_i
  sum=num+sum
  # num = num+sum if num >0
  # #or
  # if num >0 then
  #   sum=num+sum 
  # end
  # #But both "if's" serve no purpose   
end

puts"#{sum}"
```

Another way of writing this is:

```
sum = 0
gets.to_i.times{sum += gets.to_i} # no bookkeeping with cont
puts sum                          # more simple then puts"#{sum}"
```